# How do I fetch translated strings?

Tags: 8, javascript, i18n-l10n

I have a progressively decoupled Reactjs application running on top of Drupal. Its a multilingual application.

I need to fetch the translated strings from the Drupal itself and handle the translations editor and everything in Drupal itself, rather than maintaining a separate translation system for react.

How is it possible? A simple `Drupal.t()` doesn't work. I checked.

Any examples I can refer?

Comment: I am thinking of writing a preprocess function and passing the translated values using props. But this seems really complicated and not a good solution.

Comment: Any other solution that solves this problem in other ways is also good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Drupal.t()` works in this case. Have to to compile the javascript and clear the Drupal cache in order for strings to appear.

For props way:

On `get_sample_props()`:

```
function getsampleprops() {
  return ['sampleval' => t('Hello World!!!')];
}
```

On the controller,

```
$build = [
  '#theme' => 'sample_react',
  '#props' => json_encode($this->get_sample_props()),
];
```

On the template, I did:

```
<div data-component="Sample" data-prop-labels='{{props|raw}}'></div>
```

On the React side, I used

```
$val = this.props.labels.sampleval;
```

Volia, its done. Its bit inconvenient, but work gets done.